# Better way to retrieve values from matching keys in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby, xml, algorithm, hash

I'm trying to create a faster parser for a SOAP API that will turn the xml into a hash, and the match the keys with a memory loaded schema based on a YML structure. I used Nori to parse the xml into a hash:

```
hash1 = { :key1 => { :@attr1=> "value1", :key2 => { :@attribute2 => "value2" }}}
```

*(old ruby syntax to keep attributes from keys clear)*

Meanwhile I have a constant that is loaded in memory and stores the relevant keys needed for my actions:

```
hash2 = {:key1 => { :key2 => { :@attribute2 => nil }}}
```

*(old ruby syntax to keep attributes from keys clear)*

I need to match the first hash with the second one in the most efficient way. As per my understanding there are ways to do it:

Iterate over the two hash keys at the same time but by using the second one as origin:

```
def iterate(hash2, hash1)
  hash2.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a? Hash
      iterate(hash2[k], hash1[k])
    else
      hash2[k] = hash1[k]
    end
  end
end
```

*(multiline syntax, ¿clear?)*

Some questions come to my mind:

- Is there a more efficient way to do it without having to iterate over
  all my keys?
- Is this more efficient than accessing the keys directly?
- Is there a better way to parse the XML into a hash using the hash2
  inside a Visitor pattern?

Comment: I don't thinks you can avoid iteration when you have nested hashes which require recursion... seems to me like only the third question (redesign) could explore a more effective path... maybe there is a way to avoid the need to match the hashes...? Or, you could use StringScanner and write your own parser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution without iteration could be recursive select:

```
hash1 = { :key1 => { :@attr1=> "value1",
                     :key2 => { :@attribute2 => "value2" },
                     :key3 => { :@attribute4 => "value4" } },
          :key2 => { :@attribute3 => "value3" }
}
hash2 = { :key1 => { :key2 => { :@attribute2 => nil }},
          :key2 => { :@attribute3 => nil }
}

def deep_select h1, h2
  h1.select do |k, _|
    h2.keys.include? k
  end.map do |k, v|
    v.is_a?(Hash) ? [k, deep_select(v, h2[k])] : [k, v]
  end.to_h
end

puts deep_select hash1, hash2
#⇒ {:key1=>{:key2=>{:@attribute2=>"value2"}}, :key2=>{:@attribute3=>"value3"}}}
```

In general, `select` is supposed to be better than `each` because of sophisticated selection algorithm. In reality, the difference is only about 20%.

```
require 'benchmark'

hash = (1..1_000_000).map { |i| ["key#{i}", i] }.to_h
n = 5 

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  garbage = 0 
  x.report { hash.each { |_, v| garbage += v } } 
  x.report { hash.select { |_, v| (v % 1000).zero? } } 
end

#     user     system      total        real
# 0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.391305)
# 0.320000   0.000000   0.320000 (  0.321312)
```

Comment: Isn't select iterating to find al keys?

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos Generally speaking, `select` might use intelligent lookup. Updated the answer with benchmarks.

Comment: 20% is a lot when talking about a million requests. Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing this is an *ancient* question but I was looking for an answer to a question related to pattern matching and thought I'd share an updated approach for Ruby 3:

```rb
case hash1
in {key1: {key2: { "@attribute2": attr_value } } }
in {key1: {key2: { "@attribute3": attr_value } } }
end
```

and so on, matching the various hash patterns you need to account for. When the block exits, the attr_value will have the value of the matched attribute. Might need to adjust this if it matters to know whether this was an attribute2 or attribute3 value. This also does not require defining those patterns as constants any longer and gives a central location for the various forms the code expects to deal with.